# DisplayPort unable to display in 2560x1440

Tags: mac, thunderbolt, displayport, resolution, thunderbolt-display

I have a mid-2015 MBP running Mojave with 1 HDMI and 2 Thunderbolt 2 ports. I have two 32 inches Acer monitor - same model - EB321HQU with max resolution of 2560x1440. My monitors do not have DisplayPort. One monitor I have connected using HDMI and another using Thunderbolt to HDMI cable. The HDMI connected monitor is able to display at max resolution of 2560x1440 but the DisplayPort connected monitor is showing max resolution of 1600x900.

As per various articles I have read, the mid 2015 MBP should support two 4k monitors. Is there a way to get 2560x1440 on my DisplayPort based monitor? Do I need a DisplayPort 1.2 to HDMI 2 active adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Used SwitchResX and the problem got fixed.